# Is there a Selenium equivalent to Puppeteer's Page.exposeFunction()?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, puppeteer

For packaging reasons I am attempting to port a javascript using puppeteer to python using selenium.

In the javascript there is function set up in the page to replace the function in a subsequent page load. This is to allow data in the loaded page to be replaced.

Is there a selenium equivalent to this? https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.exposefunction

Comment: Python selenium, no. Javascript selenium, you can just call toString() and pass it to executeScript.